# fail soapUI test case using groovy but dont abort

Tags: testing, groovy, soapui

I have a number of test cases using groovy.

I want to be able to have the test case fail but to carry on with the rest of the script.  Tried using:

testRunner.fail( "It didn't work" )

also tried

assert false : "It didn't work"

but they both abort the test case even if the abort on error is unchecked.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hey user327697 were u able to figure out the answer for this problem.

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to fail a test case is to call the `fail()` method of Junit, rather than using `assert` or `testRunner.fail()`. However, I'm not sure whether tests subsequent to a failed test will be executed.

This `fail` method is either a static method of `Assert` or an instance method of `TestCase` depending on whether you're using JUnit 4 or 3.8.